# Run schedule jobs on Each & every Saturday 5 PM

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018

I need to create a schedule task to run my scheduled functions on **each & every week Saturday 5 PM**. ( It should run once per week that is Saturday 5 PM ).
I have experience on creating schedule on daily basics.  Also I know that we the options as '**Weekly**" in recurring drop down.  But how we can mentioned the that Saturday and 5 PM ? Because we don't have option to mention the Saturday while choose 'Weekly'

[image]

Questions:

1. If I set start date as **02-04-2022** (coming Saturday) and check Recurring options weekly and at 5:00:00 PM means, Will it run automatically on next Saturday & all upcoming Saturday also ?
2. If I choose the Crontime option, what value I should give on that textbox to run the schedule on every Saturday 5 PM? Also If I choose Crontime then do I need to give Start Date value?

Comment: Don't you just need to choose a start date from the calendar that is a saturday and time of 5pm with the weekly option selected?

Comment: Yes, That's what I my question too. Please check my above two questions @AndreasRu. Thank you !

Comment: 1. Yes. You specify the start date (header of the form) to start on that saturday, while under "frequency" you check the radio button "weekly" and set at 5.00PM. 2. the cron (tab) as specified on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron should be 0 17 * * 6 but I've never used those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Recurring: Weekly", with the time of 5 PM, and a Start Date that is a Saturday.

If you want to use the "Crontime" option, "Every Saturday, 5 PM" is

```
0 0 17 ? * SAT *
| | |  | | |   |
| | |  | | |   +- Year: Any 
| | |  | | +----- Day of Week: Saturday
| | |  | +------- Month: Any
| | |  +--------- Day of Month: not set
| | +------------ Hour: 17 (= 5 PM)
| +-------------- Minute: 0
+---------------- Second: 0
```

In both cases the task will not run before "Start Date" and not after "End Date" (if given).

- For "Recurring", setting the "Start Date" to a Saturday and "Recurring" to "Weekly" will repeat the task every Saturday.
- For "Crontime", setting the "Start Date" marks the moment when the defined schedule activates. The schedule then picks the next available trigger time ("Saturday, 5 PM") after the start date - whether the start date *itself* is a Saturday is irrelevant.